# Как отредактировать данные в localStorage по конкретному id в объекте?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Всем добрый вечер, делаю функционал редактирования формы. В данном случае на определенной странице имеется 3 карточки с заполненной информацией из 3 форм и соответственно 3 объекта в localStorage. При клике на кнопку "редактировать" на одной из карточек пользователь возвращается на одну из форм, в которой по условию появляется из localStorage. Я написал скрипт который имеет функционал редактирования объекта из localStorage, но редактирование происходит не по актуальному PassengersId, а по последнему. Как реализовать редактирование по актуальному id?

```
let currentPassengers = [{
    Name: 'Jack',
  }]

  if (passengerIdEdit) { //проверяю на наличие в форме <input type="hidden" value="">
    let passengerID;
    for (let key in currentPassengers) {
      passengerID = currentPassengers[key].PassengersId; //перебираю все имеющиеся PassengersId
    }
    let newPassengersEdit = currentPassengers.map((item) => {
      if (item.PassengersId === 49) { //если вручуную ввожу актуальный id==49 
то изменения сработают, но тут нужно вместо 49 получить 
актуальный passengerID что-то типа if (item.PassengersId === passengerID)
        return {
          ...item,
          Name: 'Bob', //перезаписываю данные
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала замените скрины кода на текст, отредактировав вопрос, нажав на "править" внизу вопроса. Во вторых, вот этим вот `passengerID = currentPassengers[key].PassengersId` вы присваиваете значение переменной каждую итерацию, как следовательно получаете последнее значение. Вам надо в эту переменную передавать значение в обработчике события нажатия на кнопку "редактировать"

Comment: Спасибо я учту всё вышеперечисленное. хотел бы еще уточнить, каким образом можно передать актуальное значение id из localStorage? Допустим 2 кнопки редактировать и 2 объекта в localStorage с [{id:1},{id:2}]. Как мне передать одно из значений по клику?

Comment: Без примера что вы делаете по клику, ответ примерно пальцем в небо: При клике, определить актуальный id и записать его в переменную, которая будет видна в внутри вашего обработчика `map`.  *(Без внятного тз, результат хз)*

Comment: Как пример, на странице предположим отрендерились 3 карточки, и 3 объекта в localStorage. Вот я написал в песочнице примерно так как вы мне предложили. arr это массив из localStorage и в коде я хочу вывести тот id за который "отвечает" кнопка. https://codepen.io/Andy41/pen/gOKPBKP Нужно сделать приблизительно вот так? Извиняюсь за тривиальные вопросы, я очень стараюсь понять.

Comment: Ну допустим, вот так можно определить, на какую кнопку жмякнули. [https://codepen.io/SwaD1984/pen/qBKbQdW](https://codepen.io/SwaD1984/pen/qBKbQdW)